# What is the purpose of `app.json`, for Expo bare workflow?

Tags: react-native, expo

If I am running the "expo bare workflow", what is the purpose of `app.json`?

For example, in `app.json`, I see:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "MyAppName",
    "slug": "MyAppName",
   ...
   "name": "MyAppName"
```

If I understand, in the bare workflow, we no longer user the Expo cli. I am not sure what the purpose of this file is for the bare workflow.

Comment: I don't use bare workflow, but your question made me curious so I tried to scan the Expo Bare workflow docs for app.json. So far, it shows if you use expo-updates, that you take advantage of OTA in bare mode with app.json helping the bundling process, as indicated here: https://docs.expo.dev/bare/updating-your-app/ -- Other than that, the app.json docs themselves seem to indicate bare workflow on in situations where you need to change native modules. I'm not sure if that means you have to ALSO do some native updates, or if the effect can ONLY be achieved with native updates..?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer to the question but I was asking myself the same thing a while ago.

[Docs](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#bare-workflow) on bare workflow: "Configuration with app.json / app.config.js is mostly not supported in this context; instead, you will need to configure each native project directly."

Note the "mostly". The [app.json / app.config.js reference](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/) is more explicit about this as it provides additional information on attributes which must be managed natively when using bare workflow. Attributes without peculiarities can be expected to be configurable from app.json / app.config.js. For instance, I'm using the `extra` property to set environment variables while I'm on bare workflow.